# Which computers am I logged into?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-domain

Hi I work in an office with many Windows computers in a Windows domain. I think my user account is logged into several of them, but I forget which ones. I'd like to log out. How can I list which computers my user account is logged in to? And how can I log out from all of them?

Comment: I don't think as a normal user you can find this information this would require the assistance of your administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Event Viewer

Windows Button > eventvwr > Enter Button

From there use the Log Filter appropriately to access your user login information:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I think you read my question backwards. I would like to know  'which other computers is my user logged in to?', not 'which other users are logged in to my computer?'

Comment: You are right! I edited my answer appropriately.